# Retreive/get row by id in SQLite, android studio doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get data from my SQLite database in android studio. The method I am trying to invoke looks like:

```
 public Cursor getDataById(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" where receipt_id="+id;
    Cursor data=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}

private void addComponentsAndData(){
        Cursor data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);

        System.out.println(data.getString(1));

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            TextView textView=new TextView(this);
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    textView.setText("ID tankowania: "+data.getString(i)+"\r\n");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView.setText("Data i czas tankowania: "+data.getString(i)+"\r\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textView.setText("Rodzaj paliwa: "+data.getString(i)+"\r\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textView.setText("Ilość paliwa: "+data.getString(i)+" l.\r\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    textView.setText("Kwota za litr: "+data.getString(i)+" zł\r\n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    textView.setText("Kwota całości: "+data.getString(i)+" zł\r\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    textView.setText("Nazwa stacji: "+data.getString(i)+"\r\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    textView.setText("Numer rejestracyjny*: "+data.getString(i)+"\r\n");
                    break;
            }
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
}
```

Database looks like:

[image]
Moreover, when i try to onvoke method, that returns all data it works:

```
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}
```

The exception i am getting looks like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.recepitscannerapp, PID: 5410
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.recepitscannerapp/com.app.recepitscannerapp.HistorySelected}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:514)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
    at com.app.recepitscannerapp.HistorySelected.addComponentsAndData(HistorySelected.java:41)
    at com.app.recepitscannerapp.HistorySelected.onCreate(HistorySelected.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Did anyone got such a problem before? I think I am making a simple mistake but i have already tried multiple things to repair it but it didn't work...

Comment: Post the code that calls `getDataById()`.

Comment: DatabaseService databaseService=new DatabaseService(this);
...................................................
Cursor data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);

Comment: These are not the lines that throw the error. The error is thrown after you get the Cursor with `data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);` when you try to get its rows/columns. Post that code.

Comment: Where selectedId is declared as: int selectedId=7;

Comment: Post the code that is executed after `data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7PH1jbr5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the cursor `data` with:

```
Cursor data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);
```

the cursor's index is positioned before the 1st row of the row(s) that it contains.
You must call `moveToFirst()` to set the index at the 1st row before you try to get any of the column values with `data.getString()`:

```
private void addComponentsAndData() {
    Cursor data=databaseService.getDataById(selectedId);
    if (!data.moveToFirst()) return;
    System.out.println(data.getString(1));
    ......................................
}
```

Also in the image I see that there are 7 columns in the table but the `for` loop in your code does 8 iterations to access 8 columns.
You should change to:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    .................
}
```

Also, the recommended way to pass parameters to `rawQuery()` is with `?` placeholders and the values of the parameters as an array of strings:

```
public Cursor getDataById(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" where receipt_id=?";
    Cursor data=db.rawQuery(query,new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
    return data;
}
```

Comment: well, that if statement solved my problem- Thank You! About for loop- i didn't attach last column of my table on screenshot, but thanks for it as well.